# Dynamics CRM 2013 same picklist on multiple entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Within Dynamics we have the same industry field on three different entities: Account, Lead & Contact. The industry field is a picklist/dropdown and contains over 30 values. Unfortunately, when we need to add a new value to the picklist, we have to add it to the fields on all three entities. This means that we have to *remember* to update the list on all of the entities...

Is there a way to have one source for the picklist? So that we can update that central source and the picklists on the entity fields will update accordingly and automatically?

FYI:

- the mapping between the entities works fine & we need to be able to see and update the list on all of the entities.
- we're using Dynamics CRM online 2013

Thanks!
Stephen

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a global option set. It is a feature introduced with CRM 2011 (works fine with CRM 2013).

You can find a tutorial here:

http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/09/12/global-option-sets-in-dynamics-crm-2011/

Answer (score 3):

Use the [OptionSetConverter](https://xrmoptionsetconverter.codeplex.com) to convert the local option sets to a Global one.  Full disclosure, I wrote it.